# Angular Dynamic Component access properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I would appreciate some help.

I need to create dynamically some new Tabs in TabView of PrimeNG, which are filled with components. It works quite well showing all components, but how can I access the properties of them?

My development is based on https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader and https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent usage example shows in the bottom part

bookingView.html contains:

```
<p-tableView>
  <p-tabPanel *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="tab.component"></ng-container
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tableView>
```

The definition of panel is stored in a Service bookingService.ts:

```
getAllInitialTabs() {
   return [
    {
      title: "BookingOverview",
      component: BookingOverviewComponent,
    },
    {
      title: "BookingDetails for US",
      component: BookingDetailsComponent,
    },
    {
      title: "BookingDetails for GER",
      component: BookingDetailsComponent,
   }
] as {title: string, component: Type<any>}[];
```

In my major component I load those server data into a tabs - array:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.tabs = this.bookingService.getAllInitialTabs();
}
```

It seemingly works, showing all Tabs in PrimeNG TabView.

But how can I access them in order to set/get some values and get callbacks if action is executed?

I tried:

```
vcr = inject(ViewContainerRef);

setFields() {
   const compRef = this.vcr.createComponent(this.tabs[0].component);
   compRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
   (<BookingOverviewComponent>compRef.instance).maxAmount = 2000;
}
```

Unfortunately, the View is not changed, old value of maxAmount stays as before.

Any ideas how can I get this created component and fill it with data? And also, how do get informations about reactions like Button Click?

Comment: Why does this need to be dynamically?

Comment: Because what components are shown and what not, and some parameter fields of those components depends on user rights.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need to resort to dynamically creating components though. I understand the need to dynamically show components based on various factors, but rarely does anyone need to resort to creating components in this way. I would reconsider your approach all together. It's likely there is a much simpler way of accomplishing what you are trying to do. I would guess you could accomplish what you need to using `ng-content` and content children.

Comment: Not really helpful this answer, sorry

Comment: Without seeing more of your application, I can't really give you any more specific guidance on how to re-architect the solution. If you would like to post a stackblitz or more code that gives greater context, I would be happy to provide a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change this order:

```
(<BookingOverviewComponent>compRef.instance).maxAmount = 2000;
compRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```